# How do I get all the posts that a certain user has liked recently with facebook graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, sdk

```
$likes = $fb->get('/' . $key['id'] . '/activity-log/likes', $key['access_token']);
                $likes = $likes->getGraphNode()->asArray();
```

This is just a random guess as to how to access all the likes, it doesn't work but there is no documentation anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the activity log with the API, what you want to achieve is not possible.

Comment: well since im using the bot just for my own account, i want to get all the posts i have liked. Can you think of another way to do this?

Comment: No there is no way to do that

Comment: the only way is to go to facebook.com and open the activity log. not sure why you would need an extra way to do that, to be honest. again: it is not possible.

Comment: im trying to make a bot that auto shares any meme i like with my main account. is there a way you know of outside facebooks api's maybe??

Comment: auto share? where? what "main account"? please explain what you mean with that. btw, "outside facebooks api" would not be allowed, we don´t discuss illegal stuff on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: its not illegal. i just want to get the url or id of all the posts that i have liked on my personal account

Comment: what i mean is that if there is another way, then it´s not allowed (because that would be scraping, which is not allowed on facebook)...either way, you did not answer my questions, they are pretty important in that matter.